# How can I parse a txt-file to get all timestamps with python?

Tags: python, datetime, parsing, timestamp

I have a txt-file with many timestamps in it. All timestamps look like this: 
"1360538289592" In front and after the timestamps there are other letters and no numbers. How can I extract all timestamps and save them for example in a list? A code example would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Example lines in txt-file:

```
1360753388030   ABC DEFGH
1360753402498   1360753423000   5.0 1504.5  0.0 0.0 45.89715971238911   12.499608526006341
1360753403454   1360753424000   5.0 1424.5  0.0 0.0 42.89715971238911   12.499608526006341
1360753404465   1360753425000   5.0 1104.5  0.0 0.0 49.89715971238911   12.499608526006341
```

Comment: Please provide a portion of your text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's Assume You have a file called `test.txt` that has data like below:

```
ABC 1500011086 Test
DEF 1500011074 TEST2
HIJ 1499929271 TEST4
```

Here the second column is your timestamps this time stamp is in UNIX format. Now the move to coding portion.

```
import datetime

lines = list(open('test.txt', 'r'))
date_list = []
for line in lines :
    date_list.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(line.split()[1])).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
```

OUTPUT :

> ['2017-07-14T11:14:46', '2017-07-14T11:14:34', '2017-07-13T12:31:11']

I hope this is what you want...

Comment: Thank you. This should work. What do I need to change if I have multiple timestamps in one line?

Comment: In this case, it would depend completely upon you being able to define the columns within the data, as you are splitting on space. If the timestamps are consistently in the same column you can use this method but the edit to your question, assigning each timestamp to a new line may be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

To extract all timestamp looking values from your text file you could use the CSV library to split each of you rows, and then attempt to convert each value into a valid `datetime` object. If the conversion is successful (and is say after 1980) then add them to a `timestamps` list. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv

timestamps = []

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
    for row in csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True):
        for value in row:
            try:
                dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(value) / 1000.0)

                if dt.year > 1980:
                    timestamps.append(dt)
            except ValueError:
                pass

print timestamps
```

For the data you have given, this would give you:

```
[datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 13, 11, 3, 8, 30000), datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 13, 11, 3, 22, 498000), datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 13, 11, 3, 43), datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 13, 11, 3, 23, 454000), datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 13, 11, 3, 44), datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 13, 11, 3, 24, 465000), datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 13, 11, 3, 45)]
```